# Conditional column visibility in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Is this possible?

I have created an expression in the TableColumn visibility-hidden field and it works fine in BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) preview but doesn't work when deployed and viewed in Internet Explorer.

```
=IIF(Parameters!n_CURRENTPERIOD.Value<Month(Now),true,false)
```

Comment: What is your conditional expression. Can you please make the question clear?

Comment: i've added to the question... but i don't think it's important- the puzzle is how it works in preview mode but not once deployed?

Comment: just a guess... the CURRENTPERIOD is having a default value and is causing the issue. @lee Did you check the value of CurrentPeriod in both cases

Comment: yes- checked the value. and as previously mentioned, can confirm it works in preview mode but not once deployed.

Comment: Try adding a couple of textbox to the report and set them to display the values for Parameters!n_CURRENTPERIOD.Value and Month(Now) - do they match what you expect?

Comment: @Lee....one possibility is that the datasource on the server is pointing to a different db. Double check that the datasources are the same in BIDS and ReportServer.  Also, have you checked th clock on the server vs your dev box?

Comment: Another possibility, extending on what Rohith Nair said above, is that the parameter default is saved on the report manager website. When you upload parameters with defaults, further uploads never overwrite the default value. It's annoying but to fix it you need to check the parameters in the properties of the report on the website.

Comment: I've done this successfully in SSRS 2005. To add to the troubleshooting: Try setting the visibility with a simple logic (1=1 or something) and see if the column is hidden with an absolute known. Also check and see if you have any merged cells, not sure if that should cause an issue. But try starting with the very basics. Simple data grid, 3 columns, add visibility condition to one column with a simple logic expression and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes it is possible.

I bet your problem is outside of your SSRS 2005 environment. Like @MikeTWebb said, are you sure you're pointing to the right data source? Also, your question is thin. Have you tried other browsers? Have you tried in VS2005 Express, which is free and in my view should be what you should be using, not BIDS.

However, the way to do it is pretty simple:

Most controls in SSRS2005 have a `Visibility` property and can be set with, as you know the `IFF()` function.

For example, looking inside the RDL of one of my reports, I control the visibility of a TableRow object as thus:

```
    <Details>
              <TableRows>
                <TableRow>
                  <Visibility>
                    <Hidden>=IIf(RowNumber("table1_Group1") &lt; 5 And Fields!CourseName.Value = "Enterprise",True,False)</Hidden>
                  </Visibility>
                  <TableCells>
..etc..
```

In SSRS2005 itself, simply point to the object you require to hide conditionally and place a similar IFF() function call there.

[image]

[image]

I am sure you know all this, but just to be sure to answer your question directly, the answer is YES!

You just need to find out more about the environment you're trying to run this in.